# How to add array of images from a folder of Xcode assets folder to ViewController?

Tags: swift, xcode, for-loop, animation, uiimage

I am trying to animate sequence of images , I added a folder called Cat_Fart in Xcode assets which holds 26 images. What I want to do is that instead of giving a single name of an image over and over again in an array and then animating it , I want to add a for loop where I would be able to call the folder holding set of images directly and want to animate from first image to last image. Please don't give answers about sprite animations because I don't know how it is done.
[image]

Now what I want to do is that , I want to give reference of this folder to my Xcode project and give starting point of the image and ending point so that I could animate this way using for loop.

[image]

Your time and help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name images in sequence order like that cat_0, cat_1, cat_2, ...., cat_25.

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.animationDuration = 1
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0
imageView.frame = CGRect(0,0,100,100)
self.view.addSubview(imageView)
imageView.animationImages = [UIImage(named: "\(0)")!]
for i in 1..<26 {
    imageView.animationImages?.append(UIImage(named: "\(i)")!)
}
imageView.startAnimating()
```